# How does variation of doping testing effect effect fairness of sports?

Tags: international-sports, doping

I have read on the internet that due to the variation of doping testing between countries and the disparity between testing standards at an international level and local level, many sports similarly turn out unfair.

People often cite examples such as East Germany and Soviet Union when they want to justify this point.

However, what about today? Is this still actually a problem today? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, doping is still a high occurrence, weakly enforced problem in sports. [One recent study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9367925/) comparing doping and socioeconomic variables points out that the WADA (World Anti Doping Association) testing protocols produce less than 1% positive results, but anonymous surveys and questioning puts the number of intentional intake at 39% (And likely higher actual value).

Another [study on testing frequency](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7525253/) shows that testing standards and frequency is vastly different from nation to nation.

Speaking at a personal n=1 level, I was a competitive cyclist (Cat 3, almost Cat 2 in the United States, so just below elite level), and I know as a fact that half the peloton at any given time was doping to some extent. Unless you are competing at a national event or in the USADA random testing pool, you aren't going to be tested.

Short answer, yes it is still a problem, and one that is not likely to be solved. Every time a new test comes out, new ways to get around it are created.